# Add node's content inside another node in hook_node_view

Tags: drupal, drupal-7, drupal-modules

In Drupal 7 i want to add node to a another node when the user is loged.

I am using Drupal 7, and I want to add a node inside another node when the user is logged in :

```
function my_modul_node_view($node, $view_mode, $langcode) {
    global $user;
    switch ($node->vid) {
    case 4:
        $node2 = node_load(37);
        if ($user->uid > 0) {
            $node->content['my_data_field'] = array(
                '#markup' => drupal_render($node2),
                '#weight' => 10,
            );   
        }
    } 
}
```

I am getting the following error message :

```
Fatal error: Cannot use object of type stdClass as array
```

I am using the following form :

```
    $form = drupal_get_form('user_login', $node);
    $node->content['data_collection_form'] = array(
        '#markup' => drupal_render($form),
        '#weight' => 10,
    );
```

What is the proper way to do this in my module?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to make one small change as far as I can tell:

```
$node->content['my_data_field'] = array(
  '#markup' => drupal_render(node_view($node)),
  '#weight' => 10,
);
```

Comment: How can include only the node plain text content?

Comment: Do you mean the body field? Something like: `$items = field_get_items('node', $node, 'body'); $body_item = array_shift($items); $body_text = $body_item['safe_value']; `